# Rust: Convert str to fixed(slices) array of u8

Tags: rust

I want to convert `str` to fixed array `[u8, 50]`, this following code does not work:

```
let str = "Hello stackoverflow user!";
let array_tmp:[u8; 50] = str.as_bytes();
```

It cause error: `expected array '[u8; 50]', found '&[u8]'`

Is there any lib to do that?

Comment: as always I would advice to share the context cause it's look strange

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the string size ahead of time, you can use this code:

```rust
let array_tmp: [u8; 25] = str.as_bytes().try_into().unwrap();
```

`str.as_bytes()` converts the `&str` into a slice of bytes - `&[u8]`.

`.try_into().unwrap()` uses [this `impl`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.59.0/src/core/array/mod.rs.html#181-190) that allows you to try to convert a slice into an array (when the element type implements `Copy`, which `u8` does).

If you only know the maximum length, and want to pad the remaining bytes, your best bet is to use [`copy_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice):

```rust
let mut array_tmp = [0u8; 50];
array_tmp[..str.len()].copy_from_slice(str.as_bytes());
```

First we initialize the array with the padding value, then fill the elements. The `[..str.len()]` is because the slice sizes has to match.